# Click Button When Not Interacting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```js
// Projects Script

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Select all the read more buttons and hidden contents
  const readMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
  const hiddenContents = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  // Now loop over the read more buttons 
  readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
    // Add onclick event listeners to all of them
    readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Change content of read more button to read less based on the textContent
      if (readMoreButton.textContent === "Read More") {
        readMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less";
      } else {
        readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
      }
      // Toggle class based on index
      hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
      readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
    })
  })
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

figure.snip1311.reading {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
  border: 3px solid #555;
}

figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 258px;
}

figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1 {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.read-more {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ScrollBar */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px transparent;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d6f6df_dd155c086895409ab4f61f494fa3108b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_440,h_320,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/footprint.webp" alt="sample94" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Sample Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu.</p>
      <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
      <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu. Quisque vehicula porttitor ultrices. Curabitur
        urna velit, auctor eget dignissim nec, commodo congue metus. Pellentesque leo ante, ullamcorper sit amet ornare eleifend, fringilla a ligula. Phasellus congue magna vitae purus pretium dapibus. Etiam in erat magna.</p>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

When you run the above code, click the `read more` button and then **hover off of the whole card**, the `read less` button does not get clicked.

### Expected Output

When the user hovers over the card, clicks the `read more` button, and then just hovers off of the whole card, the `read less` button should get clicked. The way to confirm if the `read less` button got clicked would be when the user hovers off of the whole card after clicking the `read more` button, the scrollbar would not appear. Right now, it appears when you click the `read more` button and then hover off the card, and this is because the `read less` button is not clicked.

I want the `read less` button to be clicked when the user hovers off of the whole card or stops interacting with the card. Any suggestions?

Comment: your need to rewrite so you define the hover/mouseover state with js, then toggle back the read more on mouseleave

Comment: Can you show please?

Comment: Can you try first ? using mouseenter/mouseleave events ?

Comment: I just did and followed an article from W3Schools but it did not work, and it messed up the other js that controlled the scrollbar view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to rewrite so you define the hover/mouseover state with js, then toggle back the read more on mouseleave.

Example (you may want to optimise)

```js
// Projects Script

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  document.querySelectorAll("figure.snip1311").forEach((el) => {

    // Select all the read more buttons and hidden contents
    const readMoreButtons = el.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
    const hiddenContents = el.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
    // Now loop over the read more buttons 
    readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
      // Add onclick event listeners to all of them
      readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Change content of read more button to read less based on the textContent
        if (readMoreButton.textContent === "Read More") {
          readMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less";
        } else {
          readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
        }

        readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
        hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
      })
    })

    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
      e.target.classList.add('hover')
    })

    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
      e.target.classList.remove('hover')
      setTimeout(() => {
        readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
          readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
          readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.remove("reading");
          hiddenContents[index].classList.add("hidden");
        })
      }, 600)
    })
  })
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

figure.snip1311.reading {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
  border: 3px solid #555;
}

figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 258px;
}

figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1 {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.read-more {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ScrollBar */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px transparent;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d6f6df_dd155c086895409ab4f61f494fa3108b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_440,h_320,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/footprint.webp" alt="sample94" />
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Sample Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu.</p>
      <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
      <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu. Quisque vehicula porttitor ultrices. Curabitur
        urna velit, auctor eget dignissim nec, commodo congue metus. Pellentesque leo ante, ullamcorper sit amet ornare eleifend, fringilla a ligula. Phasellus congue magna vitae purus pretium dapibus. Etiam in erat magna.</p>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

Comment: When you hover off of the card after clicking `read more` and then when you hover over the card again, I want the long text to disappear but idk why its appearing in your output

Comment: yeah test now, it was working in tiny little SO preview box in snippet editor, but when posted it broke

Comment: Yeah but when I hover on and off the card multiple times after clicking `read more` the long text still appears. Its like a glitch. It wont happen soon but when you keep hovering on and off, then you can see the long text still appears. Any way to fix that?

Comment: fixed, check again

Comment: Great last thing, and then I will take your answer and also upvote + accept it! Is there a way to make it more smooth when after you click `read more` and hover off of the card, the screen changes back to the `read more` button one? Right now there is a very quick transition of that, but I want it a little smooth when after you hover off the card, the screen should smoothly change back to the `read more` screen

Comment: ive added setTimeout so it changes back after its flipped back,  use more animations if you need tweaks, thanks for the accept

Comment: it matches the .6s (600ms) in `transition: all 0.6s ease;` so as the transition finishes it then fires that function

Comment: actually, I think it should be 350, to match `transition-delay: 0.35s;`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on calling the class click event `read-more` inside the mouse event listener `mouseleave`.

Just add this logic to your javascript code:

```
document.querySelector(".snip1311").addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("reading")) {
        readMoreButtons[0].click();
    } else {}
});
```

This logic checks for the presence of class `reading` in tag `figure`. If this class exists, then the click event *trigger* is fired. According to your code, class `reading` means **Read Less** status.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    const readMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
    const hiddenContents = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
    readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
        readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (readMoreButton.textContent === "Read More") {
                readMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less";
            } else {
                readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
            }
            hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
            readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
        });
    });
    document.querySelector(".snip1311").addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("reading")) {
            readMoreButtons[0].click();
        } else {
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 500, 800);
.project-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

figure.snip1311.reading {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

figure.snip1311 {
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 10px 1%;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 360px;
    max-height: 256px;
    width: 500rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #07090c;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-perspective: 50em;
    perspective: 50em;
    border: 3px solid #555;
}

figure.snip1311 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1311 img {
    max-width: 110%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 258px;
}

figure.snip1311 figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

figure.snip1311 h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure.snip1311 p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1 {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more1:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    transition-delay: 0;
}

figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.read-more {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* ScrollBar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: auto;
}

/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px transparent;
}

/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
    <figure class="snip1311">
        <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d6f6df_dd155c086895409ab4f61f494fa3108b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_440,h_320,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/footprint.webp" alt="sample94" />
        <figcaption>
            <h3>Sample Text</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu.</p>
            <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
            <p class="hidden">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum mi et eros finibus, eget efficitur dolor accumsan. Proin ut varius ligula. Duis et nulla eu metus congue auctor at vitae arcu. Quisque vehicula
                porttitor ultrices. Curabitur urna velit, auctor eget dignissim nec, commodo congue metus. Pellentesque leo ante, ullamcorper sit amet ornare eleifend, fringilla a ligula. Phasellus congue magna vitae purus pretium dapibus.
                Etiam in erat magna.
            </p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```